# Ayuda a fraccionar mi código para no desbordar memoria (Allowed memory size)

Tags: php, out-of-memory-error

Esta aplicación consiste en realizar permutaciones de X campos tomados de mi base de datos.

al realizar permutaciones de 6 datos el servidor responde rápidamente (3 segundos)

pero al realizar permutaciones de 7 datos hacia arriba el servidor ya lo colapso y tarda bastante.

necesito ayuda para poder liberar memoria de alguna forma en mi consulta a la hora de querer permutar 9 campos por ejemplo...

Codigo:

**--- FUNCION --**

```
 function permutar($str)
        {
        if (strlen($str) < 2)
            {
            return array($str);
            }
        $permutaciones = array();
        $cola = substr($str, 1); // 1
        foreach (permutar($cola) as $permutacion)
            {
            $longitud = strlen($permutacion);
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $longitud; $i++)
                {
                $permutaciones[] = substr($permutacion, 0, $i) . $str[0] . substr($permutacion, $i);
                }
            }
        return $permutaciones;
        }
```

**-- WHILE -- OPCION 1 --**

```
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){



                //trabajaremos con 6 campos de la base
                $n_columnas = 6;
                $columna[1] =            $row['CODIGO'];
                $columna[2] =            $row['DESCRIPCION'];
                $columna[3] =            $row['CLASE_1'];
                $columna[4] =            $row['CLASE_2'];
                $columna[5] =            $row['LED'];
                $columna[6] =            $row['APLICACION'];
                $columna[7] =            $row['VOLTAJE'];
                //$columna[8] =            $row['ESTROBOSCOPICAS'];
                //$columna[9] =            $row['GIRATORIA'];
                //$columna[10] =           $row['MAGNETICA'];
                //$columna[11] =           $row['APERNADA'];
                //$columna[12] =           $row['N_DE_LED'];
                //$columna[13] =           $row['MED_MM_ALTO_ANCHO'];
                //$columna[14] =           $row['COLOR'];
                //$columna[15] =           $row['MARCA'];
                //$columna[16] =           $row['ORIGEN'];
                //$columna[17] =           $row['TIPO_EMBALAJE'];
                //$columna[18] =           $row['MED_EMBALAJE'];


                // campos a incluir son 234567
                $n_campos  = "234567"; //

                // Se obtiene el numero de combinaciones
                $n_permuta = count(permutar($n_campos));

                // Se carga el arreglo con las combinaciones
                $a_permuta = permutar($n_campos);

                $combina_salida = '';

                echo $n_permuta;
                echo "<br><br>";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $n_permuta; $i++)
                    {
                    $separa_col = str_split($a_permuta[$i]);

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $n_columnas; $j++)
                        {
                        $combina_salida = $combina_salida.$columna[$separa_col[$j]]." ";
                        $combina_salida = strtoupper($combina_salida);
                        }
                    $combina_salida = $combina_salida . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }


                echo $combina_salida;
                echo "<br><br>";
                echo "<br><br>";
                print_r(permutar($n_campos));

                $sub_query = "UPDATE BUSCA_BALIZAS SET BUSCA = '".$combina_salida."' WHERE ID ='".$columna[1]."'";
                mysqli_query( $sub_db, $sub_query );


                }
```

**-- WHILE -- OPCION 2--**

```
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){


                // LLENADO GRUPO 1
                $n_columnas = 5;
                $columna[1] =            $row['CODIGO'];
                $columna[2] =            $row['DESCRIPCION'];
                $columna[3] =            $row['CLASE_1'];
                $columna[4] =            $row['CLASE_2'];
                $columna[5] =            $row['LED'];
                $columna[6] =            $row['APLICACION'];



                $n_campos  = "23456";
                $n_permuta = count(permutar($n_campos));
                $a_permuta = permutar($n_campos);
                $combina_salida1 = '';



                echo $n_permuta;
                echo "<br><br>";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $n_permuta; $i++)
                    {
                    $separa_col = str_split($a_permuta[$i]);

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $n_columnas; $j++)
                        {
                        $combina_salida1 = $combina_salida1.$columna[$separa_col[$j]]." ";
                        $combina_salida1 = strtoupper($combina_salida1);
                        }
                    $combina_salida1 = $combina_salida1 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }



                // LLENADO GRUPO 2
                $n_columnas = 5;
                $columna[1] =            $row['CODIGO'];
                $columna[2] =            $row['VOLTAJE'];
                $columna[3] =            $row['ESTROBOSCOPICAS'];
                $columna[4] =            $row['GIRATORIA'];
                $columna[5] =            $row['APERNADA'];
                $columna[6] =            $row['N_DE_LED'];


                $n_campos  = "23456";
                $n_permuta = count(permutar($n_campos));
                $a_permuta = permutar($n_campos);
                $combina_salida2 = '';


                echo $n_permuta;
                echo "<br><br>";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $n_permuta; $i++)
                    {
                    $separa_col = str_split($a_permuta[$i]);

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $n_columnas; $j++)
                        {
                        $combina_salida2 = $combina_salida2.$columna[$separa_col[$j]]." ";
                        $combina_salida2 = strtoupper($combina_salida2);
                        }
                    $combina_salida2 = $combina_salida2 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }


                $cadena_str = $combina_salida1." ".$combina_salida2;

                $sub_query = "UPDATE BUSCA_BALIZAS SET BUSCA = '".$cadena_str."' WHERE CODIGO ='".$columna[1]."'";
                mysqli_query( $sub_db, $sub_query );
```

Comment: ¿Te estás dando cuenta que llamas tres veces a `permutar($n_campos)` en cada iteración? Una para aplicar un `count()` y averiguar el número de elementos, otra para asignarlos a la variable `$a_permuta` y otra para el `print_r()`? Podrías haber usado un `count($a_permuta)` y `print_r($a_permuta);` para ahorrarte dos llamadas.

Comment: en `$a_permuta` Se carga el arreglo con las combinaciones

Comment: Sí, pero luego usas `print_r()` sobre una nueva llamada y lo mismo con el `count()`. Por otro lado, ¿sabías que el [orden de complejidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoría_de_la_complejidad_computacional) de tu función es **O^n**? Significa que crecerá de manera exponencial el tiempo de ejecución conforme aumenten los valores a permutar. 5 cifras son 120 combinaciones, 6 cifras son 720 combinaciones, 7 cifras serán 5.040 combinaciones, 8 cifras serán 40.320, 9 serán 362.880, etc...

Comment: @OscarGarcia si claro, tengo entendido que es un string gigantesco, es por eso que necesito buscar alguna manera de hacerlo fraccionar la permutar sin perder el O^n. en cuanto al `print_r()` simplemente lo puedo comentar.

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de como es la entrada que tienes y como debería ser la salida? es para ver si podemos pensar de otra forma tu problema.

Comment: Si me dices qué intentas hacer podría indicarte otra manera óptima de hacerlo, porque usar un algoritmo de [crecimiento exponencial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME) terminará por caer por algún lado, en tu caso por falta de memoria para almacenar todas las combinaciones en la cadena `$combina_salida`.

Comment: intente hacerlo de otra forma, como pongo arriba OPCION 2,(hacer grupos, asi libero el proceso en cada variable `$combina_salida` y al final concatenar las salidas) pero me  realiza permutacion solo de 120 por campos de 5 , cuando debiera ser en este caso por 3628800 ya que son 10 campos

Comment: ¿Pero cuál es el objetivo del código? ¿Qué intentas hacer? Por cada registro de la base de datos (tabla desconocida) permutar sus campos y actualizar una tabla llamada `BUSCA_BALIZAS` por el identificador. ***No necesitas llamar a `permutar()` en cada iteración!!*** Ya puestos, decirte que deberías usar [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) para no sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL) al concatenar cadenas de texto a consultas SQL.

Comment: @OscarGarcia el campos `BUSCA` en la BD es de tipo `LONGBLOB` almacenara el string de la permutacion `$combina_salida`. necesito hacer busquedas sobre este estring `BUSCA` de todas las combinaciones posibles..

Comment: ¿Qué tamaño tiene cada campo? Piensa que si, por poner un ejemplo pequeño, todos los campos juntos ocupan 200 caracteres, hay que multiplicar por 200 la memoria que será necesaria para almacenar las 3.628.800 combinaciones de 10 campos, que son unos 700 MB de RAM. ¿Qué límite tienes impuesto a PHP en el `php.ini` (`memory_limit`)?

Comment: Cada campo de la BD tiene un varchar de 1 A 25 maximo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84335/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-francisco-acevedo).